# Trying to pass list for a dropdown but can't find variable

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I am new to this and I have reached an impasse that has got me stuck for the past day

I have 3 tables Posts,Categories, and Users with a 1-many relationship where a category can have many posts.

The category table simply has two fields : `id` and `cat_desc`, with `id` being set as the primary key

in my postscontroller I have an add function

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $data = $this->Post->Cat->find('list', ['fields' => array('cat_desc')]);
        $this->set('cats', $data);

        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

          if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
             $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
             return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
           }
    }

    $this->set('title_for_layout',"'Add a Post");
    }
```

in my view i try to call the list for the dropdown

```
      echo $this->form->create('Post', array('action'=>'add'));
      echo $this->form->input('title');

      echo $this->Form->input('category', array('options' => array('options'=> $cats))
      );

      echo $this->form->input('amount');
      echo $this->form->input('body');
      echo $this->form->end(__('Create a Post', true));
```

I am getting an undefined variable cats. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you all for your posts as it has helped get me to this point :)

Answer (score 2):

When you first navigate to the page, the request type will be "get".  The way your code is, $cats will only be set if the request type is a "post" (so it will only be defined when you submit the form.)  Just move the code that sets $cats to outside the if statement `if($this->request->is('post'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
//controller
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

              if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                 return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
               }
        } else {

        $cats = $this->Post->Cat->find('list', ['fields' => array('cat_desc')]);
        $this->set('cats', $cats);
        $this->set('title_for_layout',"'Add a Post");
         }
        }
```

//view

```
 echo $this->Form->input('cat_id', $cats, array(options here));
```

Comment: Works like a charm Thank you so much for the response this was my first post. I hope to get to the point soon where I can contribute more  this community as well

Comment: Everything works great with the exception that it is not writing the value I select in the dropdown to the table..... can anyone tell me if I need to modify anything in the controller above?

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: Thanks Isaac, ok here goes I can get the drop down to show up as it should in the view file, however when I submit the category is not written to the posts table.

Comment: It is writing the user_id from the session data to the table just fine however the category or cat_id are not being saved to the posts table... I am going to take another vrack at it tonight

Comment: First set a name for your dropdown input. then you need to debug when you submit your form data to see if you get value from dropdown